# facebook sdk: permission "read_stream"

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using Facbook sdk and want to fetch some data from users friends wall. which permission would I need to add?

I tried with `read_stream` permission but that doesn't suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all permission in this below link

[user-friend-permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/user-friend-permissions/)

Comment: what about friend's wall/feed? I mean what permission do i need for reading from friend's wall?

Comment: You have to pass `friends_status`,`friends_activities`,`friends_likes`,`friends_photos` permissions.

Comment: If you got your result than you can accept and upward this answer buddy :)

Comment: I tried everything but not able to get the particular data when user shares some video on his wall.. do you know how to do that?